# How to count 2 rows as 1 row if they share the same values for 2 columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, tidyr, purrr

I would like to count rows as 1 row if within the same `PATIENT_ID`, the second `ADMISSION_DATE` is the same as the first `ADMISSION_DATE` and the first `DISCHARGE_DATE`.

These are the various cases that I have in the dataset:

1. **[Main part of the question]** **Case 1**: If a patient was admitted to different `INSITUTION_CODE` within the same `ADMISSION_DATE` (i.e. patient was transferred), we count this as 1 admission and attribute the admission to the institution with the later discharge date. For `PATIENT_ID1`, he was admitted to `A`, then later to `D` on the same day. When we do the counts, his `ADMISSIONS_NUMBER_TOTAL` is 1, his `ADMISSIONS_NUMBER_D` is 1 and his average length of stay (i.e. `ADMISSIONS_AVE_LOS`) is 3/1=3
2. **Case 2**: If a patient was admitted and discharge within the same day, we count this as 1 admission. For `PATIENT_ID3`, he was admitted to `B`, then later discharged on the same day. Hence, this will be counted as 1 admission. He was later admitted to `B` on another day. When we do the counts, his `ADMISSIONS_NUMBER_TOTAL` is 2, his `ADMISSIONS_NUMBER_B` is 2 and his average LOS (i.e. `ADMISSIONS_AVE_LOS`) is (0+7)/2 = 3.5
3. **Case 3**: If a patient’s DISCHARGE_DATE for the first admission is the same as his ADMISSION_DATE for the second admission (i.e. patient went home and returned to hospital for another admission), we count them as separate admissions. For `PATIENT_ID4`, he was admitted to `C` for a period of time, discharged and then admitted again. When we do the counts, his `ADMISSIONS_NUMBER_TOTAL` is 2, his `ADMISSIONS_NUMBER_C` is 2 and his average LOS (i.e. `ADMISSIONS_AVE_LOS`) is (3+7)/2 = 5

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
PATIENT_ID  VISIT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION  INSITUTION_CODE ADMISSION_DATE  DISCHARGE_DATE  LENGTH_OF_STAY  CASE_NO
PATIENT_ID1 Inpatient   A   20130225    20130225    0   CASE_NO1
PATIENT_ID1 Inpatient   D   20130225    20130228    3   CASE_NO2
PATIENT_ID2 Inpatient   A   20130604    20130604    0   CASE_NO3
PATIENT_ID3 Inpatient   B   20130503    20130503    0   CASE_NO4
PATIENT_ID3 Inpatient   B   20130508    20130515    7   CASE_NO5
PATIENT_ID4 Inpatient   C   20130628    20130701    3   CASE_NO6
PATIENT_ID4 Inpatient   C   20130701    20130708    7   CASE_NO7", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**Code:**
I wrote a code to process this data, but it only helps with addressing case 2 and 3, but not case 1.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(PATIENT_ID) %>%
  mutate(ADMISSIONS_NUMBER_TOTAL= n(),
         ADMISSIONS_NUMBER_A  = sum(INSITUTION_CODE == "A"),
         ADMISSIONS_NUMBER_B  = sum(INSITUTION_CODE == "B"),
         ADMISSIONS_NUMBER_C  = sum(INSITUTION_CODE == "C"),
         ADMISSIONS_NUMBER_D  = sum(INSITUTION_CODE == "D"),
         ADMISSIONS_NUMBER_E  = sum(INSITUTION_CODE == "E"),
         ADMISSIONS_AVE_LOS   = sum(LENGTH_OF_STAY)/n()) %>%
  slice(1) %>% ungroup() %>%
  select(PATIENT_ID, ADMISSIONS_NUMBER_TOTAL:ADMISSIONS_AVE_LOS)
```

**Desired Data:**

```
df <-  read.table(text = "
PATIENT_ID  ADMISSIONS_NUMBER_TOTAL ADMISSIONS_NUMBER_A ADMISSIONS_NUMBER_B ADMISSIONS_NUMBER_C ADMISSIONS_NUMBER_D ADMISSIONS_NUMBER_E ADMISSIONS_AVE_LOS
PATIENT_ID1 1   0   0   0   1   0   3
PATIENT_ID2 1   1   0   0   0   0   0
PATIENT_ID3 2   0   2   0   0   0   3.5
PATIENT_ID4 2   0   0   2   0   0   5", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would approach it, using the `tidyverse` suite of packages (this includes `dplyr`, but I also needed functions from `tidyr` and `purrr`).

Step1: Solve the "Case 1" problem:

```
library(tidyverse)
tmp_df <- df %>%
  split(., interaction(.$PATIENT_ID, .$ADMISSION_DATE)) %>% # from base R
  map_df(~ arrange(.x, DISCHARGE_DATE) %>% tail(1)) %>% # from `purrr`
  group_by(PATIENT_ID)
```

Step 2: Calculate general summaries:

```
df_general <- tmp_df %>% 
    summarize(
      ADMISSIONS_NUMBER_TOTAL= n(),
      ADMISSIONS_AVE_LOS = mean(LENGTH_OF_STAY)
    )
```

Step 3: Calculate institution-specific summaries:

```
df_inst <- tmp_df %>% 
  mutate(val = 1) %>%
  spread(INSITUTION_CODE, val, fill = 0) %>%  # from tidyr
  summarize_at(vars(A:D), sum) %>%
  select(PATIENT_ID, A:D) %>%
  rename_at(vars(A:D), ~paste0("ADMISSIONS_NUMBER_", .x))
```

Step 4: merge it all together:

```
df_output <- full_join(df_general, df_inst)
```

At this point, you can use `select` to rearrange the columns if the order is important.

Comment: Thanks Melissa for the answer! May understand what's been done in step 1?

Comment: I am actually working on 750k rows, so this may not be efficient. Do you know how else should I do to make this run faster?

Comment: The first step starts by splitting the data into a list of data frames, with each data frame consisting of only entries with the same `PATIENT_ID` and `ADMISSION_DATE`.  The `map` function then arranges each of these data frames by `DISCHARGE_DATE`, then take the last observation (`tail(1)`).   These are combined back into single data frame (removing the list, which is then grouped by `PATIENT_ID` to prep for the next 2 steps

Comment: With respect to speed, I'm not an expert.  My understanding is that there is a small amount of overhead associated with the `dplyr` family of functions in order to increase legibility.  The only big bottleneck I see with this is `map_df`.  This is a loop, and it's going to be slow (`split` might be too).  That said, the best way to speed up a loop is Rcpp (or another compiled language) - and I bet the code runs before either of us figure out how to translate this into Rcpp code.

Comment: Thanks to a completely random twitter retweet/reply from Hadley Wickham, I found an answer on speed/efficiency.  short answer: you're not going to do much better in R than what I've got here.  you can read more about it here: https://blog.rstudio.com/2014/01/17/introducing-dplyr/ (note that this is from 2014, when dplyr first came out)